# ORACLE query, Ignore all rows if one row meets condition for FK

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with data as below.
My requirement is to ignore all rows for FK, if FK has category M. Query should return only those rows whose category is N and type Z.
Also, FK is also given as ( in (A,B))
Basically in below example i need output to be the row for PK 5.

```
PK  FK  Category    Type
1   A       L       X
2   A       M       Y
3   A       N       Z
4   B       L       X
5   B       N       Z
6   C       L       X
7   C       M       Y
8   C       N       Z
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify sample output you require?

Comment: Sample output:          5   B       N       Z

Comment: So you need to have FK either as A or B, category should be N and type should be Z, is it the case?

Comment: Yes, but it should not return me A row because it has Category M.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try as

```
   SELECT *
  FROM tab_name
 WHERE     UPPER (category) = 'N'
       AND UPPER (type) = 'Z'
       AND UPPER (fk) IN ('A', 'B')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8240b/1)

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT 1 AS pk,
                'A' AS fk,
                'L' AS category,
                'X' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 2 AS pk,
                'A' AS fk,
                'M' AS category,
                'Y' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 3 AS pk,
                'A' AS fk,
                'N' AS category,
                'Z' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 4 AS pk,
                'B' AS fk,
                'L' AS category,
                'X' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 5 AS pk,
                'B' AS fk,
                'N' AS category,
                'Z' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 6 AS pk,
                'C' AS fk,
                'L' AS category,
                'X' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 7 AS pk,
                'C' AS fk,
                'M' AS category,
                'Y' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 8 AS pk,
                'C' AS fk,
                'N' AS category,
                'Z' AS TYPE
           FROM DUAL)
(SELECT distinct *
   FROM t
  WHERE     UPPER (category) = 'N'
        AND UPPER (TYPE) = 'Z'
        AND UPPER (fk) IN ('A', 'B'))
```

Output

```
╔════╦════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ PK ║ FK ║ CATEGORY ║ TYPE ║
╠════╬════╬══════════╬══════╣
║  3 ║ A  ║ N        ║ Z    ║
║  5 ║ B  ║ N        ║ Z    ║
╚════╩════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: @Mujahid Can you try the SQL and verify the query is providing you with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest but may be not most effective is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab_name
WHERE FK not in (SELECT FK FROM tab_name WHERE catergory='M')
```

Comment: Inner query will return me thousands of rows.

Comment: replace `with 'FK=any(select FK from tab_name minus select FK from tab_name where category='M')`. Unfortunately as you need something like 'not in' or similar it almost always at least full scan of table

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE Category = 'N' 
     AND Type = 'Z' 
     AND FK IN ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: It should not return me rows for FK, if FK has category M.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select PK, FK, Category, Type
From tab_name
Where Category = Case when Category = 'M' Then 'N' else Category end
and Type = Case when Category = 'M' Then 'Z' else Type end
and FK in ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.category = 'N' and t.type = 'Z' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.fk = t.fk and t2.category = 'M'
                 );
```

You can also us analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when category = 'M' then 1 else end) over (partition by fk) as m_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where category = 'N' and type = 'Z' and
      m_cnt = 0;
```